# "Was going to" versus "would be" as the past tense of "will"

Tags: past-tense, will-vs-going-to

Do you think that "was going to be" or "would be" could be used as past tense of *will*?

> I thought this book *was going to be* your choice.

> I thought this book *would be* your choice.

Do these two sentences basically mean the same thing or are they slightly different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're effectively equivalent, just as in the "real-world/present tense" versions...

> 1: "I think this book is going to be your choice."
>    2: "I think this book will be your choice."

You could make the same "pseudo-distinction" that #1 focusses more on the "present status" (the book is *currently destined* to be your choice), and #2 more on the "future state" (that *will* arise). But I think it's better to just call it a stylistic choice.