# "Alice could hear him sighing as if his heart would break" -- what does "would" mean here?

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

Here is a chunk from *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*:

> They had not gone far before they saw the Mock Turtle in the distance, sitting sad and lonely on a little ledge of rock, and, as they came nearer, Alice could hear him sighing **as if his heart would break**.

I wonder what *would* means here. Is it the same as *were willing*? I know that *will* and *would* can be used in if-clauses ([there is a question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181572/using-will-after-if)), but does *as if* obey the same rules?

Comment: It seems that this **would** is a 'past' form of **will**. He was signing as if his heart **was going** to break. ([a related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/was-going-to-versus-would-be-as-the-past-tense-of-will))

Comment: @CopperKettle Not _were_? I thought it was an unreal situation.

Comment: Good point. Probably yes... This is called "the irrealis '*were*'". Offhand googling led me to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/146382/48335).

Comment: As if his heart were breaking, or as if it were broken, or as if it were about to break.

Answer (score 1):

"would" is the past tense of "will" (see [britishcouncil.org](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would))

In english, we use "would" to talk about something that might happen with "if" (see more about [hypothesis and if clauses](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-time-clauses-and-if-clauses))